# Cross Walk XWalkView the super class Views methods are not being called. For e.g. onScrollChanged

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

We trying to handle the scrolling event of Cross Walk XWalkView version 12.41.296.9-x86 but the scrolling is not being called.

```
    public class CustomXWalkView extends XWalkView{

    public CustomXWalkView(Context arg0, Activity arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public CustomXWalkView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
        super(context, attrs);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        Log.d("I'm scrolling", "do");
    }
}
```

How do i get onScrollChanged event is XWalkView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below custom web view solved my problem. Hope it helps

```
package com.example.crosswalkexample;

import org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;
import org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomCrossWalkView extends XWalkView implements ContentViewCore.InternalAccessDelegate {


    private XWalkViewBridge mWalkViewBridge;
    private ContentViewCore mContentViewCore;

    public CustomCrossWalkView(Context context, Activity arg1) {
        super(context, arg1);
        init();
    }

    public CustomCrossWalkView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        if(this.getChildCount() > 0){
            mWalkViewBridge = (XWalkViewBridge) this.getChildAt(0);
        }else{
            throw new Error("XWalkWebView Bridge not found");
        }
        mContentViewCore = mWalkViewBridge.getXWalkContentForTest();
        mContentViewCore.setContainerViewInternals(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean super_awakenScrollBars(int arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean super_dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean super_dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void super_onConfigurationChanged(Configuration arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean super_onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean super_onKeyUp(int arg0, KeyEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean awakenScrollBars() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.awakenScrollBars();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onScrollChanged", "Scorlling");
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }


}
```

Comment: I had to use and extend XWalkViewInternal because of some specifics of my project, and this custom class became simplified in that there was no XWalkViewBridge to use, but it was possible to directly call getXWalkContentForTest to obtain the core needed to observe scrolling.